# Find unused classes in a .net project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, refactoring

I have a VS.NET 2008 project. Is it possible to check for classes that are not used anywere in the project? With FXcop I can find unused variables and unused code, but not unused classes.

Comment: Be careful when deleting classes. It might still be used by code behind a preprocessor or used by a project that isn't currently loaded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tool [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) can help find unused code in a .NET code base. *Disclaimer: I am one of the developer of this tool.*

To elaborate a bit, NDepend proposes to write [Code Rule over LINQ Query (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). Around [200 default code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed, 3 of them being dedicated to *unused/dead code* detection

Basically such a rule to detect unused method for example looks like:

```
// <Name>Dead Methods</Name>
warnif count > 0 
from m in Application.Methods where !m.MethodsCallingMe.Any()
select m
```

[image: NDepend rule to find unused methods (dead methods)]

But this rule is naive and will return trivial false positives. There are many situations where a method is never called yet it is not unused (entry point, class constructor, finaliser...) this is why the 3 default rules are more elaborated:

- [Potentially dead Types](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Types.html) (hence detect unused class, struct, interface, delegate...)
- [Potentially dead Methods](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Methods.html)
- [Potentially dead Fields](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Fields.html)

NDepend is integrated in Visual Studio, hence these rules can be [checked/browsed/edited right inside the IDE](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx). The tool can also be integrated into your CI process and it can build [reports](http://www.ndepend.com/SampleReports.aspx) that will show rules violated and culprit code elements.

If you click these 3 links toward the source code of these rules, you'll see that the ones concerning types and methods are a bit complex. This is because they detect not only unused types and methods, but also types and methods used *only* by unused dead types and methods (recursive).

This is *static analysis*, hence the prefix *Potentially* in the rule names. If a code element is used *only* through reflection, these rules might consider it as unused which is not the case.

In addition to using these 3 rules, I'd advise measuring code coverage by tests and striving for having full coverage. Often, you'll see that code that cannot be covered by tests, is actually *unused/dead* code that can be safely discarded. This is especially useful in complex algorithms where it is not clear if a branch of code is reachable or not.

Answer (score 4):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (with solution-wide checking on) automatically notified you of unused classes in your project & solution

Comment: is there any way to run a "report" to tell me which classes in my solution are unused all at once?